# Why is every Noetherian zero-dimensional scheme finite discrete?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, krull-dimension

In the book [*The geometry of schemes* by **Eisenbud** and **Harris**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387986375), at page 27 we find the exercise asserting that

> **Exercise I.XXXVI.**
>   The underlying space of a zero-dimensional scheme is discrete; if the scheme is Noetherian, it is finite.

**Thoughts**
I thought that a zero-dimensional scheme is one such that, in every local ring $\mathscr O_{X,p}$, the only prime ideal is its unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak m_{X,p}.$ Hence, supposing that $X=\operatorname{Spec} R$ is affine, we deduce that every prime ideal is maximal, so each ponit in $X$ is closed. But how does this imply the discreteness? It only implies the Hausdorff-ness of $X$, right?
Furthermore, I cannot perceive what the "Noetherianity" has to do with the finiteness claimed here. In the affine case, it seems to be claiming that there are only a finite number of prime ideals in a Noetherian ring, if its scheme is zero-dimensional? For example, $\mathbb Z$ is a Dedekind domain, hence its scheme is zero-dimensional, but it has infinitely many primes: does this contradict the statement?

Thanks in advance for any reference or hint, and point out any inappropriate point if any is presented.
**Edit** I see why my example cannot work now: it is one-dimensinoal: don't forget the pirme $(0)$. But I am still wondering why the statement is true...

Comment: My answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299361/question-on-discrete-variety/299366#299366) might be relevant for your second question. The point is that the underlying space of a noetherian scheme is a noetherian space, and that a Hausdorff space (e.g. a discrete space), which is also noetherian must be finite.

Comment: @NilsMatthes Thanks for that answer: it is really helpful. Now I only have to show that the underslying space is Hausdorff if the scheme is of dimension $0$.

Comment: Sorry I had to delete my answer, it was early in the morning and there were many things wrong with it.

Comment: @PVAL No Problem! BTW, the preperty that every point is closed only implies the $T_1$ separation, not Hausdorff. So this becomes more and more confusing. :(

Comment: It is **false** in the absence of noetherianity that a zero-dimensional scheme (even if assumed affine) has the discrete topology: see my answer.

Comment: My edition of Eisenbud and Harris has Exercise 1.36 as: 
"The underlying space of a zero-dimensional Noetherian
scheme is finite"

Comment: @Dorebell Apparently that edition contains some errors, in my opinion, in view of the wonderful answers below.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

a) A noetherian zero-dimensional  scheme is covered by finitely many open affines which are spectra of zero-dimensional noetherian rings.
If these spectra are discrete finite, then the scheme is discrete finite too.
 This answers the second part of your question.

b)  Here is why  the spectrum $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ of a zero-dimensional ring $A$ is Hausdorff:
Consider  two distinct points of $X$, i.e. two maximal ideals  $\mathfrak m,\mathfrak n\subset A$.
There exist idempotent elements  $m\in \mathfrak m, n\in \mathfrak n$ with $m+n=1$.
The  disjoint open subsets  $  D(n), D(m)$ are then separating neighbourhoods of  $\mathfrak m$ and  $\mathfrak n$.
 The details (and more) are to be found in the Stacks Project [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ER).

c) If moreover $A$ is noetherian, then $X=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is finite and thus discrete.
Inded a noetherian ring  has only finitely many *minimal* prime ideals and all primes are minimal in a zero-dimensional ring.

d) It is **false** that the spectrum of a zero-dimensional ring is discrete if the ring is not assumed noetherian:
If $A=K^\mathbb N$ is the denumerable power  of a field $K$ then $A$ is zero-dimensional and  $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is homeomorphic to the Stone-Čech compactification of $\mathbb N$, a dreadful beast which is certainly not discrete since it is compact and infinite.

Comment: For a synthesis of properties of rings of dimension zero, you might look [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/106069/3217).

Comment: Hmm, sorry, but why do the idempotents in b) exist? Unfortunately, I don't see this immediately. There must be some argument that $\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ is not connected, but I don't see how to obtain this, or proceed from there.

Comment: Dear @Nils: you might look [here](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00ER), in  the Stacks Project by De Jong and collaborators.

Comment: Might ask what do the symbols $D(m), D(n)$ mean? Also, do you mind to prove the fact that every Noetherian ring has only a finite number of minimal primes? Thanks.

Comment: Great Georges, thank you very much!

Comment: Dear awllower: $D(m)$ denotes the set of primes of $A$ which do **not** contain $m$, i.e. $D(m)=Spec(A)\setminus V(f)$.The finiteness of the set of minimal primes results from Atiyah-Macdonald: Proposition 4.6+Theorem 7.13 (applied to the zero ideal).

Comment: OK. I shall check that result, after I get my hands on Atiyah-Macdonald again. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to Georges's excellent answer, I think it is worth noting a systematic construction of non-discrete zero-dimensional schemes.

Start with an arbitrary scheme $S$, say noetherian to simply what follows. There is a finer topology on $S$ than the initial one, called the *constructible topology* on $S$. The open subsets for this topology consists in constructible subsets of $S$ (i.e. finite union of locally closed subsets). Denote this topological space by $S^{\rm cons}$. It turns out that $S^{\rm cons}$ is always totally disconnected and compact, see EGA IV.1.9.15 ($S$ is noetherian hence quasi-compact and quasi-separated). **Edit** So $S^{\rm cons}$ is discrete if and only if $S$ is finite (set-theoretically).

To finish, and this was really surprising for me, such a "dreadful beast" is the underlying space of a scheme ! See EGA IV.1.9.16. So

> $S^{\rm cons}$ is non-discrete and zero-dimensional for any noetherian scheme such that the underlying space is infinite.

If $S_1, S_2$ are two integral algebraic varieties not birational to each other, then $S_1^{\rm cons}$ is not isomorphic to $S_2^{\rm cons}$ by looking at residue fields.

Comment: Dear Cantlog, I'm impressed by your erudition: have you read all of EGA? +1 (although I'm too ignorant  to have checked everything you wrote)

Comment: Thanks @GeorgesElencwajg! I only search in EGA when I need some information on specific subjects or results . This masterpiece is kind of intimidating for me.