# When is the generic point of an integral noetherian scheme open (reference)?

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let $X$ be an integral noetherian scheme, let $\xi$ be its generic point. Then it is not so hard to show that $\{ \xi\}$ is open in $X$ if and only if $X$ is a finite set. In termes of algebra, it says the following:

> Let $A$ be a noetherian integral domain. Suppose there exists $f\in A$ non-zero such that the localization $A_f$ is a field. Then $A$ is semi-local of Krull dimension at most $1$.

**Question**: What is the name of this result ? I am sure I saw it once somewhere.

The motivation comes from a construction of non-discrete zero-dimensional schemes  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474873/).

Comment: @YACP: thanks ! Do you mind to convert your comment into an answer ? Meanwhile I found the place where I saw this statement attributed to Artin-Tate, it is in Görtz and Wedhorn, Appendix B.62.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is attributed to Artin and Tate: see [Theorem 2.13](http://people.fas.harvard.edu/~amathew/CRing.pdf), pg. 281.